# How to handle the initial UIViewController after dissmissing the one on top of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

mHello everyone

First excuse me if I use incorrect terms. I am having trouble with viewControllers. I have a viewController that I access through a navigationController (triggered segues: rootViewcontroller->firstviewcontroller)

Now I am on the firstviewcontroller, it invokes "viewdidLoad" and if the user is not logged in, it performs a modal segue to the loginViewController.

After I deal with the login issues on this view,   I perform

```
         [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

it dismisses the logincontroller and takes me back to the firstviewController without a problem.

Now my problem is that, this dismiss action, -without a surprise- doesn't invoke "viewDidLoad" again (so that I can check if the user is logged in). I am wondering if I can automatically invoke any part of my firstViewController after the dismissal of the second one, so that I can automatically check for login status and perform actions accordingly.

Thanks a lot

arda

Comment: Unrelated note: My "Hello everyone" phrase got cropped when I posted this. I added a random letter (m). Are we not allowed to greet people here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `-viewWillAppear:` method in firstViewController. It will be called after you dismiss the login controller.

Another way is to make your firstViewController to be a delegate of the login controller. Once you're done with the login procedure, you can call the delegate to dismiss the presented view controller and to update the subviews

Comment: `-viewDidLoad` is not invoked once again because the view controller's view doesn't get unloaded when a modal view controller is presented, so there's no need to load the view once again. There is an exception in pre iOS6 environments though. When an app receives a memory warning it does unload the views of non-presented controllers, so in this case the `-viewDidLoad` will be called consequently when the current modal view controller is dismissed.

Comment: You sir made my day! I knew it was easy,I even read the docs for this, I didn't realize it until now. Gotta sleep I guess. Thanks a lot